# How to check if a "Send Query" is over?

Tags: sql, r, database, rsqlite

I need to check if my `res` from `dbSendQuery()` is over.

My code is like this:

```
db <- dbConnect(drv=SQLite(),flags=SQLITE_RW,dbname="db.sqlite",synchronous = "off")
dbBegin(db)
res <- dbSendQuery(db,"Update Operation SET Name = 'teste' where Id = 1")
if("my SendQuery is over"){
  dbClearResult(res)
  dbCommit(db)
  dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

I need to know when it is over to send this to commit and then disconnect.

UPDATE 1
Im my sistem, for this example above can happen with more than 1 users simultaneous.
Then, when the first connection in db is over, i need to finish him requisition and provide to the other connection the possibility to write your query.

Comment: I just saw your edit, didn't receive a notification. -- What happens when two users (processes? threads?) access the database simultaneously with this code?

Comment: @krlmr right now, when two user's use the db simultaneous, the second have a erro saying "data base is locked" because the first is using, and i can't check to waiting the first disconnect.

Answer (score 3):

`dbSendQuery()` always awaits completion. You can double-check by calling `dbGetRowsAffected(res)` .

For SQL statements that are run for the side effect and do not return a value, `dbSendStatement()` is preferred.

The `synchronous = "off"` argument to `dbConnect()` is a misnomer, this defines when and how the data is written to disk; no multi-threading is involved here.

Comment: This is a example, in my system has multiple acess in data base.
Becauase of this i need to check if the send is over.

Comment: Can you please rephrase, and perhaps expand your example to better cover your use case?